# View body of email in 2 columns

Tags: ms-word, outlook

Does anybody know if MS Outlook has the functionality where the user can set his email body to be displayed/read in more than 1 column?
Similar to MS Word-> Page Layout-> Columns (Page Setup tab).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Outlook has that functionality (yet).